# JQ using bash variable gives me wrong output

Tags: json, templates, jq, instantiation

i need to insert ~400 values  i.e  `"a","b"` from bash variable *$a* into *template.json*

```json
{
  "trials": [],
  "targetState": "EDIT",
  "force": false
}
```

My command:
`jq --arg value "$a"  '.trials |= . + [$value]' data/template.json > new_file.json`

gives result :

```json
{
  "trials": [
    "\"a\",\"b\""
  ],
  "targetState": "RELEASE",
  "force": false
}
```

However i need : `["a","b"]`

thx for any help.

Comment: How about `--argjson value "[$a]"`?

Comment: almost perfect, but it's add [ ] along with values

Answer (score 0):

If $a is too long to be passed in on the command line as per @oguzismail’s ingenious suggestion, then you could pass it in by some other means and use:

```
"[\($a)]" | fromjson
```

or

```
"[\(.)]" | fromjson
```

as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You have not been clear on the format of the input.

---

Is it CSV?

`jq` doesn't provide a CSV parser, so you'd have to write your own or use something else to convert the CSV to JSON.

---

Is it a JSON array body? If so, then you can use any of the following:

```sh
jq --argjson new_trials "[$a]" \
   '.trials |= . + $new_trials' template.json
```

```sh
printf %s "[$a]" |
   jq --argfile tmpl template.json -n \
      '$tmpl | .trials |= . + input'
```

```sh
printf %s "$a" |
   jq --argfile tmpl template.json -Rn \
      '$tmpl | .trials |= . + ( input | "[\(.)]" | fromjson )'
```

In all cases, the output is

```json
{
  "trials": [
    "a",
    "b"
  ],
  "targetState": "EDIT",
  "force": false
}
```